# Perform proposed action VS code

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I use a class which can be imported VS Code will show me a small icon that it can help me with importing:

[image]

Is there a hotkey to perform the proposed action instead of pointing on it with a pointer?

Comment: Ctrl+. is listed as "Quick Fix" in the [key bindings list](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_keyboard-shortcuts-reference). Can't seem to get it to pop up in VSCode, but in Visual Studio it brings up the quick fix (lightbulb) menu.

Comment: @pmcoltrane, works. do you want to transform it to an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Light bulb" icon is referred to as "Quick Fix" in the keybindings documentation. The [default hotkey](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_keyboard-shortcuts-reference) to access the quick fix menu is `Ctrl+.` (`Command+.` on MacOS).